# Access DB inner join

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, inner-join

I have 2 tables

tbl1

```
Pr23      Ba1    Suf12  WTKg    PBS
8A61    A218K02   12      0.4    8A61-A218K02-12
8A61    A218K02   22      0.99   8A61-A218K02-22
A3455   D34GH44   11      56     A3455-D34GH44-11
```

tbl2

```
Pr23      Ba1    Suf12   WTKg    PBS
8A61    A218K02   12     0.16    8A61-A218K02-12
```

I'm trying to get matched records between two tables with the query INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl1.Pr23,tbl1.Ba1,tbl1.Suf12,tbl1.PBS,
tbl1.WTKg AS Wt1,tbl2.WTKg AS Wt2
FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.PBS = tbl2.PBS
```

Result

```
Pr23      Ba1    Suf12    Wt1    Wt2         PBS
8A61    A218K02   12      0.4    **0.16**   8A61-A218K02-12
8A61    A218K02   22      0.99   **0.16**   8A61-A218K02-22
```

In the result Wt2 column gets duplicate 0.16 value, instead of that is there anyway to replace 0 or null

Like

```
Pr23      Ba1    Suf12    Wt1     Wt2         PBS
8A61    A218K02   12      0.4    0.16   8A61-A218K02-12
8A61    A218K02   22      0.99   0      8A61-A218K02-22
```

Comment: Not easily with MS Access.  Such changes are often done at the application layer.

Comment: Also, it is unclear why the second matched record should receive 0 or null? There is no logic to code for it. What if 10 records matched?

Comment: There should be a logic to decide which record you want to make WT2 zero or null. It can be based on another column for an instance you can allocate WT2 for the Record with MAX Wt1. Whatever it is you need to have a logic to allocate or zero out a column.

Comment: I just set up your exact conditions including the table values. I always get a return of a single row. The only way I could get the results close to what you show from that query is if the 8A61-A218K02-22 PBS in Tbl1 were really 8A61-A218K02-12. I tried it with an Access query and VBA. Maybe I'm missing something. Do you have additional info to help?